# Lambda writing empty records to s3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to write from firehose to s3 using the test event

```
{ 
  "TICKER_SYMBOL": "QXZ",
  "SECTOR": "HEALTHCARE",
   "CHANGE": -0.05,
   "PRICE": 84.51
}
```

My lambda code is

```
import json
import base64
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    for record in event['records']:
       #Kinesis data is base64 encoded so decode here
        payload=base64.b64decode(record["data"])
        print("Decoded payload: " + str(payload))
        json_object = {}
        output = []
        output_record = {
            'recordId': record['recordId'],
            'result': 'Ok',
            'data': base64.b64encode(json.dumps(json_object).encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')}
        output.append(output_record)
        print(output)
    return {'records': output}
```

The code prints the expected output and kinesis is writing to the successful s3 folder but when I download the file from s3 it is just an empty {}. What is causing the empty {} in s3?

Comment: How is this code related to firehose or s3? You don't read any files from S3, nor you write anything to S3.

Comment: The event comes from a kinesis stream in that event format and the lambda performs the data transformation, although in this case it is just returning the same data back to the stream.

Comment: So what `json_object` should be? Its always empty in your code. You never do nothing with it after you define it.

Comment: are you sure there's no Glue transformer attached? Then Glue could remove all fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is causing the empty {} in s3?

The Lambda function is serializing `json_object`, which is an empty dictionary `{}`. If you want to serialize/return the original payload with no transformations, serialize/return the original, undecoded data:

```py
output_record = {
    'recordId': record['recordId'],
    'result': 'Ok',
    'data': record['data']
}
output.append(output_record)
```

Kinesis Firehose can be configured to sink to S3 without configuring Data Transformation with Lambda. If you don't require any data transformations, my suggestion is to exclude the Data Transformation configuration.

If you do require data transformations, make sure to...

1. Perform transformations on `payload`
2. **Fix bug**: Move `output = []` outside of `for` loop
3. Serialize/return transformed `payload`

```py
output = []

for record in event['records']:
    payload = base64.b64decode(record["data"])
    payload_json = json.loads(payload)   

    # TODO: do transformations on payload_json
    transformed_payload = json.dumps(payload_json)
     
    output_record = {
        'recordId': record['recordId'],
        'result': 'Ok',
        'data': base64.b64encode(transformed_payload.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
    }
    output.append(output_record)

return {'records': output}
```